# Blueimp plugin with angular : preview image on the web page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, blueimp

I have a feature that allows my client to design his own personal portal, I would like to allow my user to preview a picture from his computer prior to uploading it to the server.
is it possible?.

No docs, and no result on Google, if anyone wonders why am I asking such an allegedly stupid question.

IMPORTANT: I am using this library since it has support for some deprecated browsers such as IE 8-9, hence I need a solution that can work without file API, or a good reliable file API fallback for old IE versions.